El mapa de calor no muestra en las cuadrículas los valores de la correlación entre las columnas del DataFrame
Intento hacer un mapa de calor con el código siguiente
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import Timestamp

# Mostrar el diccionario
df_correlacion_dict = {'Date': {0: Timestamp('2011-02-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2011-02-02 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2011-02-03 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2011-02-04 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2011-02-07 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2011-02-08 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2011-02-09 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2011-02-10 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2011-02-11 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2011-02-14 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('2011-02-15 00:00:00'),
  11: Timestamp('2011-02-16 00:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('2011-02-17 00:00:00'),
  13: Timestamp('2011-02-18 00:00:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2011-02-22 00:00:00'),
  15: Timestamp('2011-02-23 00:00:00'),
  16: Timestamp('2011-02-24 00:00:00'),
  17: Timestamp('2011-02-25 00:00:00'),
  18: Timestamp('2011-02-28 00:00:00')},
 'rating_base': {0: 'Codicia Extrema',
  1: 'Codicia',
  2: 'Codicia Extrema',
  3: 'Codicia',
  4: 'Codicia Extrema',
  5: 'Codicia Extrema',
  6: 'Codicia Extrema',
  7: 'Codicia Extrema',
  8: 'Codicia Extrema',
  9: 'Codicia Extrema',
  10: 'Codicia Extrema',
  11: 'Codicia Extrema',
  12: 'Codicia Extrema',
  13: 'Codicia Extrema',
  14: 'Codicia',
  15: 'Neutral',
  16: 'Neutral',
  17: 'Codicia',
  18: 'Codicia'},
 'rating_cuartiles': {0: 'Codicia',
  1: 'Neutral',
  2: 'Codicia',
  3: 'Neutral',
  4: 'Codicia',
  5: 'Codicia',
  6: 'Codicia',
  7: 'Codicia',
  8: 'Codicia',
  9: 'Codicia',
  10: 'Codicia',
  11: 'Codicia',
  12: 'Codicia',
  13: 'Codicia',
  14: 'Neutral',
  15: 'Neutral',
  16: 'Miedo',
  17: 'Neutral',
  18: 'Neutral'},
 'rating_clustering': {0: 'Codicia Extrema',
  1: 'Codicia',
  2: 'Codicia',
  3: 'Codicia',
  4: 'Codicia',
  5: 'Codicia Extrema',
  6: 'Codicia Extrema',
  7: 'Codicia Extrema',
  8: 'Codicia Extrema',
  9: 'Codicia Extrema',
  10: 'Codicia Extrema',
  11: 'Codicia Extrema',
  12: 'Codicia Extrema',
  13: 'Codicia Extrema',
  14: 'Neutral',
  15: 'Neutral',
  16: 'Neutral',
  17: 'Neutral',
  18: 'Codicia'},
 'rating_std': {0: 'Codicia',
  1: 'Neutral',
  2: 'Codicia',
  3: 'Neutral',
  4: 'Codicia',
  5: 'Codicia',
  6: 'Codicia',
  7: 'Codicia',
  8: 'Codicia',
  9: 'Codicia',
  10: 'Codicia',
  11: 'Codicia',
  12: 'Codicia',
  13: 'Codicia',
  14: 'Neutral',
  15: 'Neutral',
  16: 'Neutral',
  17: 'Neutral',
  18: 'Neutral'},
 'rating_percentiles': {0: 'Codicia',
  1: 'Neutral',
  2: 'Codicia',
  3: 'Neutral',
  4: 'Codicia',
  5: 'Codicia',
  6: 'Codicia',
  7: 'Codicia',
  8: 'Codicia',
  9: 'Codicia',
  10: 'Codicia',
  11: 'Codicia',
  12: 'Codicia',
  13: 'Codicia',
  14: 'Neutral',
  15: 'Neutral',
  16: 'Miedo',
  17: 'Neutral',
  18: 'Neutral'}}

# Convertir el diccionario en un DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df_correlacion_dict)

# Eliminar la columna 'Date'
df = df.drop(columns=['Date'])

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Crear un diccionario para mapear las etiquetas a valores numéricos
rating_map = {
    'Miedo Extremo': 1,
    'Miedo': 2,
    'Neutral': 3,
    'Codicia': 4,
    'Codicia Extrema': 5
}

# Convertir las columnas de etiquetas a valores numéricos
df_numerico = df.apply(lambda col: col.map(rating_map))

# Verificar los datos después de la conversión
print("Datos convertidos a valores numéricos:")
print(df_numerico.head())

# Calcular la matriz de correlación
correlation_matrix = df_numerico.corr()

# Verificar la matriz de correlación
print("Matriz de correlación calculada:")
print(correlation_matrix)

# Crear el mapa de calor
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))  # Aumentar el tamaño de la figura
sns.heatmap(correlation_matrix, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', fmt='.2f', linewidths=0.5, 
            square=True, annot_kws={"size": 10})  # Ajustar el tamaño de las anotaciones
plt.title('Mapa de Calor de Correlaciones entre Métodos de Fear & Greed Index', fontsize=15)
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()

Devuelve


Vemos que en las cuadrículas del mapa, no muestra los valores de la correlación entre las diferentes columnas del DataFraem. ¿Donde está el fallo?. Agradeceré ayuda.

¿Qué versión de seaborn tienes instalada? En mi caso no puedo reproducir el error con seaborn 0.13.2, pero si que es un bug conocido de seaborn 0.12: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3478

Efectivamente, tengo la versión 0.12.2

He actualizado a la versión 0.13.2 y ya opera correctamente. Gracias
